# How to factor $x^3 + 27$

Tags: factoring

> How to factor $x^3 + 27$

I know cube roots are involved though, I tried to factor out the cube roots but I wasnt able to figure out a way to do so

Comment: Real or complex factorization?

Comment: $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint:

$$x^3\pm a^3=(x\pm a)(x^2\mp ax+a^2)$$